# How to make Feed Forward NN more accurate?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, classification

I just finished writing my first ever Neural Network and it finally works, but it works really bad. I get about 0.37 accuracy. Any tips on how to make it more accurate? I have already tried different learning rates and also different number of hidden layer units, but I never get above 0.37 accuracy. I'm trying to classify data into one of the 3 classes 0, 1 or 2. I use a 1 hot Matrix as my Y. How could I improve my code?

```
X = data[1:, 2:]
m, n = X.shape
labels = data[1:, 1]

Y = np.zeros((m,3))
i = 0
for label in labels:
    if label == 0:
        Y[i,0] = 1
    elif label == 1:
        Y[i,1] = 1
    elif label == 2:
        Y[i,2] = 1

    i += 1


 slice_size = math.floor(m/5)

 X_test = X[-slice_size:, :]
 Y_test = Y[-slice_size:]
 X_train = X[:slice_size, :]
 Y_train = Y[:slice_size]

learning_rate = 0.00001
num_steps = 200
batch_size = 100
display_step = 2

n_nodes_hl1 = 5
n_nodes_hl2 = 5
n_nodes_hl3 = 5

n_classes = 3
n_inputs = 16

training_epochs = 500

x = tf.placeholder('float32', [None,n])
y = tf.placeholder('float32', [None, n_classes])

weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_inputs, n_nodes_hl1])),
    'h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, n_nodes_hl2])),
    'h3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2, n_nodes_hl3])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, n_classes]))
}
biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1])),
    'b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2])),
    'b3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
}


def neural_network(data):

    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])

    layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['h2']), biases['b2'])

    layer_3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['h3']), biases['b3'])

    output = tf.matmul(layer_3, weights['out']) + biases['out']

    return output



 logits = neural_network(x)
 prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits)


 loss_op = 
 tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=logits, 
 labels=y))

 optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
 train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss_op)

 correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(Y_train, 1))
 accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

 # Initialize the variables (i.e. assign their default value)
 init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

 with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(init)
    for step in range(1, num_steps+1):
        x_step = np.asarray(X_train[step,:])
        y_step = np.asarray(Y_train[step])
        x_step = np.reshape(x_step, (1, n))
        y_step = np.reshape(y_step, (1,n_classes))

        sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={x:x_step , y:y_step})
        if step % display_step == 0 or step == 1:
             #Calculate batch loss and accuracy
             loss, acc = sess.run([loss_op, accuracy], feed_dict={x: x_step,
                                                             y: y_step})
             print("Step " + str(step) + ", Minibatch Loss= " +
                  "{:.4f}".format(loss) + ", Training Accuracy= " +
                  "{:.3f}".format(acc))
     x_step_test = np.asarray(X_test)
     y_step_test = np.asarray(Y_test)
     x_step_test = np.reshape(x_step, (1, n))
     y_step_test = np.reshape(y_step, (1,n_classes))
     print("Optimization Finished!")
     print("Testing Accuracy:",
          sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: x_step_test,
                                    y: y_step_test}))
```

Comment: Neural networks are not magic.  Perhaps .37 is the best that can be done with your data.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy then you don't see a fundamental problem in my code? Because that's what I thought initially

Comment: That is a different question.  The lines from `slice_size...` to `Y_train` have a one-space indent, which is a SyntaxError.  It should be 0 (likely) or 4 spaces (unlikely).  I cannot comment on the use of TensorFlow.  I have worked with traditional classification methods and know that success is (necessarily) quite variable.

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
 x_step_test = np.asarray(X_test)
 y_step_test = np.asarray(Y_test)
 x_step_test = np.reshape(x_step, (1, n))
 y_step_test = np.reshape(y_step, (1,n_classes))
```

Shouldn't this be:

```
 x_step_test = np.asarray(X_test)
 y_step_test = np.asarray(Y_test)
 x_step_test = np.reshape(x_step_test, (1, n))
 y_step_test = np.reshape(y_step_test, (1,n_classes))
```

Also check how u r taking the batches, there might be some problem.

2. Use `train_test_split` from `sklearn.model_selection`, it splits your train and test data after shuffling. Not shuffling your data might create problem if ur data have some pattern, eg. u have 99 data points, first 33 contain its a dog another 33 contains its a cat and for last 33 its a mouse, your neural net will train only on 66 dog and cat images and won't learn to recognise mouse.
3. Increase the learning rate, AdamOptimizer already decays the lr, use something like 0.1 or 0.01.

I guess tensorflow part is correct.